# SQL Server - Assign default DateTime value to parameters in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Maybe I'm being an idiot here, but I'm trying to assign a default DateTime value to a Stored Procedure in MS SQL Server 2005 but can't get it to work eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
(
    @MyInteger    INT = 123,
    @MyDateTime   DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '1753-01-01 00:00:00', 20)
)
AS
BEGIN ... (snip)
```

So if the `@MyDateTime` input parameter isn't specified, it should use '1753-01-01 00:00:00' by default, but I get the error...

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.
```

I can get it to work for Integers just fine. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** from the answers below, I eventually went with the following inside the Sproc itself:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
(
    @MyInteger    INT = 123,
    @MyDateTime   DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @MyDateTime = COALESCE(@MyDateTime, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1753-01-01 00:00:00', 20))

    ...snip...
END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@MyDateTime   DATETIME ='1753-01-01 00:00:00'`

Or right within the sproc you can do this:

`SELECT @MyDateTime = (SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, '1753-01-01 00:00:00', 20))`

The error is due to calling CONVERT, which you cannot do when defaulting parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Just using a string works, but assumes a specific date format set by the SQL Server instance that I don't want to rely on (yyyy-dd-mm in my case), can the format be controlled? Or I might just resort to setting it within the Sproc itself.

Comment: @Sunday Ironfoot, simply call the convert right after `SET NOCOUNT ON` or at the beginning of your stored procedure.  There is where you can call convert.

Comment: I settled for putting the following after my SET NOCOUNT ON - SET @MyDateTime = COALESCE(@MyDateTime, CONVERT(DATETIME, '9999-12-31 23:59:59', 20)) - thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: Yep, I do this with GETDATE() as well

Answer (score 4):

You can't have the CONVERT() function call in there, just assign the default value using the relevent datetime string.